# How to cycle through a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to work out the correct method for cycling through a number of pandas dataframes using a 'for loop'. All of them contain 'year' columns from 1960 to 2016, and from each df I want to remove the columns '1960' to '1995'.

I created a list of dfs and also a list of str values for the years.

```
dflist = [apass,rtrack,gdp,pop]
dfnewlist =[]
for i in range(1960, 1996):
    dfnewlist.append(str(i)) 
for df in dflist:
    df = df.drop(dfnewlist, axis = 1)
```

My for loop runs without error, but it does not remove the columns.

Edit - Just to add, when I do this manually without the for loop, such as below, it works fine:

```
gdp = gdp.drop(dfnewlist, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure some robustness, you can us the `errors='ignore'` flag just in case one of the columns doesn't exist, the drop won't error out.

However, your real problem is that when you loop, `df` starts by referring to the thing in the list.  But then you overwrite the name `df` by assigning to that name the results of `df.drop(dfnewlist, axis=1)`.  This does **not** replace the dataframe in your list as you'd hoped but creates a new name `df` that no longer points to the item in the list.

Instead, you can use the `inplace=True` flag.

```
drop_these = [*map(str, range(1960, 1996)]

for df in dflist:
    df.drop(drop_these, axis=1, errors='ignore', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Great - the extra argument works. I'm assuming that the first line is a better way of creating the list of years? I assumed there was one. Unfortunately that created an error message for me.

Comment: you probably have an older version of Python that doesn't allow for the unpacking syntax.  `drop_these = list(map(str, range(1960, 1996)))` should work

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issues for people in for loops. When you say

```
for df in dflist:
```

and then change df, the changes do not happen to the actual object in the list, just to `df`

use `enumerate` to fix

```
for i,df in enumerate(dflist):
    dflist[i]=df.drop(dfnewlist,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; however the above code didn't work for me. I copied it in exactly.

Comment: I played around a bit - when i call dflist[0] it appears to work. However when I call the df directly it's showing with the columns still.

Comment: @BenG What version of python are you using? this works for me